# how to pass value to rotate method on menu item click?

Tags: java, image, swing, menu

i am developing application of rotating image.
as user click menu item as per that image should be rotate.
right now i have implemented keyboard listener, in which as user press right to left button it moves but i want to change that method and want as per menu item click.

right now it passes degrees variable to method rotate, now i want to custom that and as user click menu item it pass the value.
i don't know how to do.

my code:

```
public class RotateIMGn extends JPanel {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("D://Workspace//ScaleImage//src//images//img.png");
  JLabel label = new JLabel(image);
  JPanel rotationPanel;
  final int WIDTH = 350;
  final int HEIGHT = 500;
  double degrees;

  public RotateIMGn() {

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(446, 500));

    setFocusable(true);

    addKeyListener(new KeyboardListener());
    rotationPanel = new JPanel();
    rotationPanel = new turningCanvas();
    rotationPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight()));
    add(rotationPanel);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    add(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("Rotate");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    ImageIcon icon90 = createImageIcon("/images/images_Right.png");
    JMenuItem mntmTR90 = new JMenuItem("Rotate 90+", icon90);

    mntmTR90.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
    });

    mnFile.add(mntmTR90);

    ImageIcon icon180 = createImageIcon("/images/images_Vertical.png");
    JMenuItem mntmRT180 = new JMenuItem("Rotate 180+", icon180);
    mnFile.add(mntmRT180);

    JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
    mnFile.add(separator);

    ImageIcon micon90 = createImageIcon("/images/images_Left.png");
    JMenuItem mntmTRM90 = new JMenuItem("Rotate 90-", micon90);
    mnFile.add(mntmTRM90);

    ImageIcon micon180 = createImageIcon("/images/images_Horizontal.png");
    JMenuItem mntmRTM180 = new JMenuItem("Rotate 180-", micon180);
    mnFile.add(mntmRTM180);
    rotationPanel.setBounds(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2,
        rotationPanel.getPreferredSize().width,

        rotationPanel.getPreferredSize().height);
    degrees = 0;
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
  }

  public class turningCanvas extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), image.getIconWidth() / 2,
          image.getIconHeight() / 2);
      image.paintIcon(this, g2d, 0, 0);

    }
  }

  public class KeyboardListener implements KeyListener {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
      if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        degrees--;
        repaint();
      }
      if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        degrees++;
        repaint();
      }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RotateIMGn test = new RotateIMGn();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setContentPane(test);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = RotateIMGn.class.getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
      return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
      System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

> anyone's idea will help me a lot so...

Comment: where is the rotate method?

Comment: in paint component method. rotate is inbuilt method of Graphics2D. i have to just pass value of degrees. but how to pass it i don't know.

Comment: oh, sorry, i thought rotate was a custom method. you can use Math.toRadians to pass an argument in Radians to the rotate function. It would be useful to see paintComponent though

Comment: i know i have to pass value to that function but how to pass it. is it possible through switch case or other method ?? if any possibility to pass value as degree then pls tell me.

Comment: all you have to do is `g2d.rotate(angle)`

Comment: yes that i know, but how to pass value of menu item click as a angle or degree that i don't know. how to check which menu item is clicked and pass value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Swing `Action`s for the menu items instead of `String`s. Then, in the `actionPerformed` method, update the `degrees`variable, as you do your `KeyListener`.

Something like:

```
ImageIcon icon90 = createImageIcon("/images/images_Right.png");
JMenuItem mntmTR90 = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Rotate 90+", icon90) {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        degrees += 90;
        repaint();
    }
});
```

Comment: beat me to it. damn. +1 anyway :)

Comment: ya that's work haraldK, thank u thank u so much. so are wonderful guide man. i have done my work only and only because of you.